# Apple In-App Purchase: How apple use the applicationusername to Detecting Irregular Activity?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In apple's document, it says developer can use the applicationusername to [Detecting Irregular Activity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/RequestPayment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW6)，but i don't know how to use it.The document just says hash a userId,but how can i detect the irrgular activity? Does the apple's server have a server API to notify me ?

Here the link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/RequestPayment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW6

Comment: Did you find the answer ?

Comment: @lapin  Sorry,no...

Answer (score 0):

Let's day your app uses an account system so each user has an identifier (email, username etc) which we refer as appId here and the app store login as appleId

Scenario:

Say user purchased a subscription with a trial period (txn123) with appId usr123 having appleId appl123
Later she unsubscribed the subscription.
After few months she changed the AppleID for some reason.
Again she wants to purchase the subscription.
She will login into the app using same appId, usr123.
As she already has used trial with that appId, your app will recognise her, and will show buy button to her.
When she will click on the Buy button, Apple UI will show that she is  eligible for Trial, and will be charged after 7 days.

If you had passed the `applicationUserName` field in the payment(payment object) in the both the transaction user makes, apple will recognise that and may take a remedial action (like actually charging the user instead of offering a second trial period).

At this point I am not sure, how Apple is going to inform your app/ecosystem about this irregular activity. I have not tested this scenario myself as yet, will update the answer once I have done so.

Several things may happen:

1. Apple declines the second purchase because it detects the irregular activity of the same user purchasing the trial period again. But how would Apple know if the user is intentionally trying to make the purchase now after trial has expired. Anyways, apple can say that this user seems to be associated with some other apple id also which has made a purchase in the past, thus not allowing the transaction with the pair.
2. Apple may actually charge the user, since they are trying to buy after a trial but in this case Apple will be offering a Apple Id user without a trial period in their name.
3. Apple may allow the transaction with trial period offering and may resolve this through other/offline channel.